# What is unfold for C++?

Tags: c++, functional-programming

C++ has [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

> std::accumulate performs a left fold. In order to perform a right
>   fold, one must reverse the order of the arguments to the binary
>   operator, and use reverse iterators.

[Kwang's Haskell Blog -- unfold and fold](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2016-12-12-unfold-and-fold.html)

> unfoldr builds a list from a seed value while foldr reduces a list to
>   a summary value.

What is 'unfold' for C++?

Answer (score 2):

[`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

> Fills the range [first, last) with sequentially increasing values, starting with value and repetitively evaluating ++value.

[`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) / [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n).

> Assigns each element in range [first, last) a value generated by the given function object g.
>
> Assigns values, generated by given function object g, to the first count elements in the range beginning at first, if count>0. Does nothing otherwise.

Comment: Is there also a version of `std::generate`, which passes the index to the generator function? `Ret generator(size_t i)` instead of `Ret generator()`?